# With CDatabase, can I send SQL without using CRecordSet?

Tags: c++, mfc, odbc

When using the MFC class CDatabase to connect to a data source, is there any way to execute SQL statements without having to open a CRecordSet object?  I ask because CRecordSet::Open() appears to throw an exception when I use it to call stored procedures that don't return anything - and there's no reason to expect results from, say, sp`_`delete`_`row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use CDatabase::ExecuteSQL()

```
CDatabase database;
//database is connected somewhere
database.ExecuteSql("Drop table [users]");  // sql statement from little Johnny Drop tables
```

Comment: Don't have time to test this at the moment, but it looks like the right thing so I'm accepting it on trust.  Thanks very much.

His name was Bobby, not Johnny, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a CCommand directly to perform a scalar query.