# How to execute stored procedure without exception thrown by CRecordset::Open?

Tags: sql-server, mfc

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure on SQL Server from an MFC based C++ program.  The stored procedure does get executed properly, but an exception is thrown in my program, a CDBException with a message of "Function sequence error".  Tracing through the MFC source code for CRecordset::Open, the exception is thrown from MoveNext - this makes sense, as my stored procedure isn't generating any output.

I have both input and output parameters to the stored procedure, so I can't use CDatabase::ExecuteSQL as suggested in this question:
[With CDatabase, can I send SQL without using CRecordSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839739/with-cdatabase-can-i-send-sql-without-using-crecordset)

Comment: Looking at your score, my suggestion might sound dumb. You can modify the stored procedure to return 1 (i.e. put SELECT 1 at the end).

Comment: I don't know if this works. But you could combine the call to SP with SELECT 1 (e.g. mystoredproc @x, @y; SELECT 1)

Comment: @shahkalpesh - not so dumb, if you had left it as an answer I would have given it an upvote. And don't let the score mislead you, I'll bet there are even a couple of things Jon Skeet doesn't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with a hack to fix the problem, I couldn't wait for S.O. to provide an answer. I had already traced the problem to CRecordSet::MoveNext, which immediately calls CRecordset::Move.  What I didn't immediately realize is that Move is declared virtual, so it's possible to bypass it with my own version.

```
void CMyRecordset::Move(long nRows, WORD wFetchType)
{
    (void) nRows;
    (void) wFetchType;
    m_bEOF = true;
}
```